# Geth on two machines on same network

Tags: go-ethereum, peers

I'm new to geth mining. I have 2 machines one of which is mining and second one is syncing. Each have it's own accounts. I just started the geth with "geth --datadir /blah/blah" --mine --miner.threads 6.

1. Now what is my next step?
2. Does it enough on mainnet mining to get ether into the account when it is supposed?
3. What is smart contract? Do I need one really?

Comment: Hi Raj. I would suggest that you split your question in two separate questions. 1, 2 and 3 are questions on mining. 4 has to do with geth nodes networking. You should remove 4 from this question (edit) and post a new question with 4. You may get more answer that way.

Comment: Are the nodes connected to each other? A node cannot mine until it has finished syncing, if it doing so while syncing then it is wasting cpu.

Comment: Thanks Ismael. Nodes are not interconnected when tried to mine with chainid 1 & network id 1. But they are able to communicate if I use other network id and connected to a testnet. Any Idea?